# Get the data from sub collection after filtering the field of collection using where clause and provide it to stream builder

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Access the chats(sub collection) if user field contains my Username]

This is the code I tried

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection("ChatRoom") .where("users", arrayContains: Constant.myname) .snapshots(); 
@override

Widget ChatMessageList() { return StreamBuilder(   
 //  stream: chatMessageStream,
    stream: _usersStream,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.data == null) {
        return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          color: Colors.orange.shade600,
        ));
      } else {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.2,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                QuerySnapshot<Object?>? snap = snapshot.data; // Snapshot
                List<DocumentSnapshot> items =
                    snap!.docs; // List of Documents
                DocumentSnapshot item = items[index];
                String v = item['chatroomid'];
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("ChatRoom/$v/chats")
                          .orderBy("time", descending: true)
                          .limit(1)
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot2) {
                        if (snapshot2.hasData) {
                          QuerySnapshot<Object?>? snap2 =
                              snapshot2.data; // Snapshot
                          List<DocumentSnapshot?>? items2 =
                              snap2?.docs; // List of Documents
                          DocumentSnapshot? item2 = items2?[0];
                          print(item2?['message']);
                          return MessageTile(
                            username: item['chatroomid']
                                .toString()
                                .replaceAll("_", "")
                                .replaceAll(Constant.myname, ""),
                            chatroomid: item['chatroomid'],
                          );
                        } else {
                          return CircularProgressIndicator();
                        }
                      }),
                );
              }),
        );
      }
    });
}
```

This is the code. One streamBuilder to get the users with where Condition. ListViewBuilder to Display users and second streamBuilder to fetch the last message from the chat sub collection.

But I am facing this issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error image, I believe your issue is coming from here:

```dart
List<DocumentSnapshot?>? items2 = snap2?.docs; // List of Documents
DocumentSnapshot? item2 = items2?[0];
```

You are assuming that there will always be a document in the list. You need to consider an empty list scenario.

Answer (score 0):

why can you use `combinestream`  using [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart)

```
StreamBuilder(
stream: CombineLatestStream.list([
  stream0,
  stream1,
]),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  final data0 = snapshot.data[0];
  final data1 = snapshot.data[1];
})
```

Comment: Two streams are not independent of each other the data fetched from stream1 has to be passed to fetch the data from stream 2. In that case will it be useful?                                              In the first stream I am fetching the users I have had conversations with and after fetching that users in the second stream I am fetching the last message between two. I hope I made my point clear                                                        Thank you for your time

Comment: the second stream is a sub collection for a stream1. since is like that then just get the document and filter it